# JPanel size by inner components

Tags: java, user-interface, swing

Is it possible to tell JPanel to set its size to fit all components that it contains? Something like `pack()` for JFrame.

edit: The trick with preferredSize didn't help. I've got JSplitPane, where in one part there is GridBagLayout with many labels (see screenshot) and labels overlap each other.

[screenshot http://foto.darth.cz/pictures/screen.png](http://foto.darth.cz/pictures/screen.png)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

After looking at the source code for `pack()`, I came up with:

```
    panel.setPreferredSize(panel.getPreferredSize());
```

This forces the panel to recalculate its preferred size based on the preferred sizes of its subcomponenents.

You may or may not have to call [`validate()`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Container.html#validate()) afterward; in my tiny example, it seemed to make no difference, but the Javadoc says:

> The `validate` method is used to cause a container to lay out its subcomponents again. It should be invoked when this container's subcomponents are modified (added to or removed from the container, or layout-related information changed) after the container has been displayed.

So I guess it depends on why you're having to repack your `JPanel`.

Comment: Thanks.It'll be ok if you don't setSize, setPreferredSize or setMinimumSize.

Answer (score 4):

By default `Container`s have a preferred size that matches the preferred layout size given by the container. So literally all you have to do is:

```
panel.setSize(panel.getPreferredSize());
```

Presumably you are doing something odd with the parent to stop the parent's layout manager doing the equivalent of this.

Answer (score 2):

maybe you can do something like that by removing from your panel

setResizable(false);

Answer (score 1):

I would try:

```
panel.revalidate();
panel.repaint();
```

This will not necessarily set the panel to its preferred size, that is more dependent on what the layout manager decides to use.

This is useful in cases where you have added/removed components from a panel that is currently displayed and visible.

Update:
Based on your screenshot I can say the following:
1) Consider programatically changing the divider location.
2) Consider programatically resizing the window itself horizontally since it seems to be a little tight to show both sides of the split pane.
Or both.
You can set the divider location by doing

```
splitPane.setDividerLocation(newSize);
```

Keep in mind that there are two overloaded methods for this, one taking a float one taking an int. The float does a percentage of the size while the int is the size in pixels. The size is for the left hand panel (or top panel for that orientation).
I would consider possibly changing the divider location based on the preferred width of the panels.

Answer (score 1):

The javax.swing mysteries reveal themselves only gradually, and only to those who are prepared to offer many libations (particularly torn out clumps of hair, hours burning the midnight oil, etc.) to the gods of Swing.

However, for this case in point I would suggest the following as a sort of Swiss army knife which usually does what you think the framework should do anyway:

```
myJPanel.getTopLevelAncestor().validate()
```

As the sacred text says, "Validates this container and all of its subcomponents." (Container.validate). NB getTopLevelAncestor() is a JComponent method.

Can't remember how JSplitPane fits into this: try it and you'll probably find that it validates both components (right and left, top and bottom), but I would be surprised if changing the divider doesn't do this for you anyway.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue using **Netbeans GUI Builder**. My inner panels were getting weird sizes; I was trying to adjust the minimum and preferred sizes manually, which was a frustrating exercise.

The problem was solved when I **reset all the minimum and preferred sizes back to default** (In Netbeans GUI Builder: right click JPanel component -> Properties -> preferredSize -> Reset to Default). *When there is no imposed size, the jpanel takes the size of the inner component.*

*Note: GridBaLayout was used in my case*

Answer (score 0):

JSplitPanes are a bit fussy when it comes to its children's sizes, have a look at [the Java tutorial](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/uiswing/components/splitpane.html#divider). Are you using the GridBagLayout correctly? Looks like it's not setting the right JPanel's minimum size properly.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example of a panel which:

- Resizes with it's parent.
- Sets the width to the width of the parent.
- Sets the height according to sum of the height of all of it's children.

```
JPanel panel = JPanel(new GridBagLayout())

panel.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(panel.getMaximumSize().width, panel.getPreferredSize().height))

panel.validate()
panel.repaint()
```